# Local setup after disabling Magento_TwoFactorAuth admin panel still ask for Security Code

Tags: magento2, module, authentication

After local setup, I have disabled Magento_TwoFactorAuth and changed the value of Magento_TwoFactorAuth to 0 in config.php

[image]

[image]

and still can't log in to the admin panel Security Code:

[image]

After changing values I have tried:

```
se:up
s:d:c
c:c
c:f
```

Any sugestions?

Magento 2.4.3-p1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing value of Amasty_SecurityAuth to 0 solved issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do using command line also. After running the below command cache flush and check.

**php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth**